Trouble with 3D Fourier transform of a cross product expression
I don't understand a Fourier transform identity that has been quoted with no source in several papers (relevant to quantum mechanics):
$$
\vec f(\vec r_i)=\int \frac{\vec r_i - \vec r_j}{|\vec r_i - \vec r_j|^3}\times \vec{A}(\vec r_j) d^3 \vec r_j  \overset{F.T.}{\Rightarrow}  \tilde{\vec f}(\vec k)=-4\pi i\frac{\vec k}{|\vec k|^2}\times\tilde{\vec{A}}(\vec k)
$$
Where $\vec r_i, \vec r_j, \vec k \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathcal{F}[\vec A(\vec r)]=\tilde{\vec A}(\vec k)$. This is said to hold for any non-singular function $\vec{A}(\vec r)$.
How can this be derived? I am totally lost on what to do with the cross product, but I think the fact that $\frac{\vec r_i - \vec r_j}{|\vec r_i - \vec r_j|^3} = \vec \nabla_{r_i} \frac{1}{|\vec r_i - \vec r_j |}$ may be relevant. I am also interested in how important the non-singular condition is.

Let $g(\vec r)=\frac1{|\vec r|}$ and $f(\vec r)$ be given by the integral
$$\begin{align}
f(\vec r)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{|\vec r-\vec r'|^3}\times \vec A(\vec r')\,d^3\vec r'\\\\
&=\nabla \times \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}g(\vec r-\vec r')\vec A(\vec r') \,d^3\vec r'\\\\
&=\nabla \times \vec B(\vec r)\\\\\tag1
\end{align}$$
Taking the Fourier Transform of $(1)$, and using the Convolution Theorem , we find that
$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{F}\{f\}(\vec k)&=-i\vec k\times \mathscr{F}\{\vec B\}(\vec k)\\\\
&=-i\vec k\times \left(\mathscr{F}\{g\}(\vec k)\right)\left(\mathscr{F}\{\vec A\}(\vec k)\right)
\end{align}$$
Now, since the Fourier Transform of $g$ is
$$\mathscr{F}\{g\}(\vec k)=\frac{4\pi}{k^2}$$
we obtain the coveted result!
